# Launch overlay activity without showing the rest of the app

Tags: android, android-intent, overlay, kotlin

I currently have an app composed of multiple activities, one of which is a translucent one. The app has notifications, and when I tap it, I want it to open the translucent activity on top of whatever is currently on the screen. As of now, this works if my app is closed, but if it is running and my overlay activity opens, the rest of my app is also in the foreground. I'd like to make it so that only the overlay is there, and once the user presses back, it will go back to their original app.

This sort of mimics google chrome's tab activity.

I am currently launching my activity through a PendingIntent:

```
val intent = Intent(context, WebOverlayActivity::class.java)
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
intent.putExtra(ARG_URL, ...)
intent.action = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() //dummy action
val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right).toBundle()
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, bundle)
```

Those flags are what I have when I launch the activity elsewhere, but they don't seem to affect this pending intent. As mentioned, this activity is translucent and draws over other activities.

I feel like this involves me separating this activity from the rest of the app tasks, but I also use the overlay within my app and am not sure if that will affect anything.

Any ideas?

Edit 1: Here is the activity manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".WebOverlayActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Overlay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!--other data sources-->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I've added my activity manifest in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a viable solution.
The goal is to launch the activity in a new task, so I did so by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the activity manifest. What messed me up was that I also need to specify a `taskAffinity`, otherwise the launchMode would be ignored.

I can now effectively use the overlay to load urls in other apps and go back to it, or use it from my own app and have it behave like any other activity.